# Return value depending on distribution of values in other cells

Tags: excel

I have a table with the following cells:

```
 |           A            |   B   |   C
1|Histidine               |1000 mg| ### mg
2|Isoleucine              |2000 mg| ### mg
3|Leucine                 |3900 mg| ### mg
4|Lysine                  |3000 mg| ### mg
5|Methionine + Cysteine   |1500 mg| ### mg
6|Phenylalanine + Tyrosine|2500 mg| ### mg
7|Threonine               |1500 mg| ### mg
8|Tryptophan              | 400 mg| ### mg
9|Valine                  |2600 mg| ### mg
```

*The milligram unit in the B & C columns aren't actually written, instead they're formatted (0 "mg").*

### Must-know theory

The table of the top has the nine essential amino acids (AAs) the body needs (we can't produce them, so they should be obtained through food/supplements. Column A), with the corresponding amounts (in mg. Column B) per 100 kg of a food.

A *complete protein* is the one that has an **adequate¹** proportion of each of the nine essential AAs. This means that, per 100 kg the closer a food has its AA amounts to the ones from the B column, the better.

Note that all foods can have the nine essential AAs.

*¹: adequate beacause it doesn't have to have the amounts for all nine AAs exactly as in the B column. However, they must be pretty close, whether they're **higher** or lower*.

### The Problem

So, in the C column, I'm going to type the AA values of a food (e.g. apple). Basically, **what I want is a cell (let's say E1) to give the value of "1" if *all* of the AA amounts of C column are *exact* to the ones of the B column**.

Thus, as a value from the C column is further from the corresponding of the B column, the lower the value of E1 goes from 1.

In general, there should be a proper distribution of all nine AAs (now we'll suppose "proper"/"adequate" means a returned value of 0.75 or higher).

### Example

Let's *suppose* apples have the following values:

```
 |           A            |   B   |   C
1|Histidine               |1000 mg|  500 mg
2|Isoleucine              |2000 mg| 1000 mg
3|Leucine                 |3900 mg| 1950 mg
4|Lysine                  |3000 mg| 1500 mg
5|Methionine + Cysteine   |1500 mg|  750 mg
6|Phenylalanine + Tyrosine|2500 mg| 1250 mg
7|Threonine               |1500 mg|  750 mg
8|Tryptophan              | 400 mg|  200 mg
9|Valine                  |2600 mg| 1300 mg
```

As you can see, they have coincidentally half of the values of B column per 100 kg of apples. This means that the value of cell E1 will be 0.5.

### One suggested solution

I've thought of an idea that could work, although I haven't figured out how to apply it.

Instead of giving the value directly in cell E1, we could first give a value in D column applying the same mechanism of the "1" value (1 = exact amount for *each* AA). So, we'd have:

```
 |           A            |   B   |   C    | D
1|Histidine               |1000 mg|  500 mg|0.5
2|Isoleucine              |2000 mg| 1000 mg|0.5
3|Leucine                 |3900 mg| 1950 mg|0.5
4|Lysine                  |3000 mg| 1500 mg|0.5
5|Methionine + Cysteine   |1500 mg|  750 mg|0.5
6|Phenylalanine + Tyrosine|2500 mg| 1250 mg|0.5
7|Threonine               |1500 mg|  750 mg|0.5
8|Tryptophan              | 400 mg|  200 mg|0.5
9|Valine                  |2600 mg| 1300 mg|0.5
```

After this we simply find the average for cells D1:D9, and show that average result in E1. *Voilà!*

Comment: Don't use average. If you have 1 high and 1 low by the same amount you could get a false positive. Use countif for the range against 1 of the values in the range. If you get 9 then there is a true proposition.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is sum up all the values in column C and then divide that by all the values in column B.  That will get you a value of 1 in the case when the values match and value 0.5 when they are half.  Obviously will also work for anything in-between as well.  So in cell E1 all you need to put is:

```
=SUM(C1:C9)/SUM(B1:B9)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C1:C9/B1:B9>=0.75))
```

as a starting point which will give you a count of 9 if all the food values (column C) are at least 75% of the required values (column B) or you could just add a helper column containing C1/B1 etc. and do a COUNTIF.